# After Home button pressed, my Activity not reload when launch it again from click icon app

Tags: java, android

My activity UI have a CheckBox which set default check is "unchecked".
I have a receiver to listen when a new incoming SMS, then the checkBox will be set "checked".

**And this is my steps:**

1. Open activity for first time.
2. Press Home button to let my app to background
3. From another phone, send a SMS to my phone.
4. Launch app again by click icon app

Result : The CheckBox still is uncheck. (It means my activity not reload yet)

I try to long press Home button and then remove my app from the list app, then launch app again by click icon app, after that the CheckBox is checked.

Can anybody help me explain for this ? 
And how can I reload my activity without removing app from list background apps ? 
Thanks

Comment: Some code would help. It seems some UI reloading is happening inside `onCreate()`. Instead do it in `onResume()` to update the view when coming from background. If you remove the app from background and restart, it will call `onCreate`. However if you just come back from background `onCreate` is not called.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri Great, it is correct, I change the update UI code on onResume() and it work well now. Thanks you. I can not mark your answer is Solution because you only just comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems some UI reloading is happening inside `onCreate()`. Instead do it in `onResume()` to update the view when user is opening the app from background. 
If you remove the app from background and then start it, it will call onCreate. However if you just come back from background `onResume` is called but not `onCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

Try sharing code while asking questions.
Meanwhile do read about activity life cycle.After that check where you have implemented code to enable check option and see if it is getting called while coming back to application. It is probably not getting called and that is where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

In your receiver listener save a variable in the shared preferences to indicate the state of the checkbox. Then in your on `onCreate()` activity grab the state from the shared preferences and update the ui accordingly.